# Running ASP page at startup of index.html page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

> When a user loads the website's homepage (which will be the index.html page), I'd like my index.aspx to also load. So if I go to www.mywebsite.com/index.html it should run through the Page_Load method on the index.aspx.cs page (C# language).

I've done this in the past and I cannot recall how I did so. Eventually I'd like to perform ajax calls on my index.html page... so I will need to check for the api call that I'm making in the Page_Load method of my index.aspx.cs page.

I thought I had to just include `runat="server"` for this to work. Currently, I'm just running the page locally through the debugger (launching Chrome) to test everything. Will it not work like this?

**ASP page:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.index" ValidateRequest="false" runat="server" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>wtf</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**ASP class code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("ASP page loaded.");
        }
    }
}
```

**index.html page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    index.html page
</body>
</html>
```

I'm still new to setting things up with ASP... so maybe I'm missing something here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirements don't make any sense and reflect a misunderstanding of how ASP, Ajax, and HTML work. I think you need to read and learn more about them.

Anyway, to answer your question. HTML pages don't normally get passed by ISS to the ASP engine, so it doesn't really matter what you put in them (e.g. `runat="server"`) because the ASP engine will not even be aware of it. IIS will simply send the pages unprocessed to the browser which does not understand the marking and simply ignores it.

If you want IIS to send HTML pages to the ASP engine, you need to tell it to do so. The steps vary depending on your IIS version. For IIS 6:

- Open the properties of your website
- Select the **Home Directory** tab
- Click on the **Configuration** button
- Edit your .aspx entry and copy the path
- Create a new extension for .htm (and .html if you want) and paste the path from the previous step.

For IIS 7, if you are running your app pool in the **Classic Mode**:

- Go to your website
- Go to the **Handler Mappings** section
- Make a copy of the entries for `Path=.aspx`
- Change the copy to from `.aspx` to `.htm`
- You can make another copy and change to `.html` if you like

If you're using the **Integrated Mode**, then you don't need to do any of the above, just continue with the steps below.

Now that IIS will pass HTML pages to the ASP engine, you need to tell the ASP engine what to do with them. In your web.config file, add a new entry to the `httpHandlers` section like this:

```
<httpHandlers>
   <add path="*.htm" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" />
   <add path="*.html" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" />
</httpHandlers>
```